# UIScrollView inside UIPageViewController overlapping. Bug or not?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview

I have UIViewController that contains UIPageViewController that contains UIScrollView.

```
- UIViewController
    - UIPageViewController
        - UIScrollView
            -UIView (purple)
            -UIView (orange)
```

And there is a problem. When I try to leaf page but not completely (staying on the same page) , there is **overlapping of pages**. Just look at this:

[image: 1]

On the right. It a part from right page!

**GitHub project:**
https://github.com/maratsarbasov/Bug-or-not-XCode-6.1.1-

It is pretty simple (I specifically created it to show it to you). Please download it and compile.

Is there any way to get rid of this?

Thank you!

PS. Xcode 6.1.1. iOS 8.1 simulator. Using Auto Layout.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your leading and trailing and top constraint of the scrollview are relative to the margin.
Uncheck relative to margin and set their constant to 0 this will fix your problem.
let me know if that works out.

Comment: Maaaan, you are awesome! It works! I could not fix this for whole day.Thank you very much!!!

Comment: I had an overlapping issue on the storyboard with tableView headers inside a page view controller. Can't believe this margin thing is what solved the issue. My overlap was like half a screen.

Comment: Other than that, you will want to "Clip Subviews" if the photo is bigger than the frame especially when you choose "Aspect Fill".

Answer (score 2):

Was having a similar problem but in my case it was because I was using 'Aspect Fill' in an image view. If you're doing that make sure you tick the 'clip subviews' checkbox to prevent the imageview breaking out of the page bounds

Answer (score 0):

set `clipsToBounds` to `true` in your content view